# Program exiting when no input given and alert dialog not fixing the error

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, seekbar

Here's the Program, it works and all but when I Pull the seek bar when there is not number in the input box the program exits and the alert dialog is not doing its job even though i put a try and catch on the code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SeekBar sbCash;
    private Button btnten,btntwenty,btnthirty;
    private TextView tvShwProg,tvfinal;
    private EditText etCash;
    final Context context = this;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etCash = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCash);
        sbCash = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbCash);
        tvShwProg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShwProg);
        tvfinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFinal);
        btnten = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnten);
        btntwenty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btntwenty);
        btnthirty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnthirty);

        etCash.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
            {


            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) 
            {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

                try{
                guiChanged();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errormessage();
                }
            }


        });


        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener sbListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
            {
                try{
                guiChanged();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errormessage();

                }
            }


        };
        sbCash.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(sbListener);

        dosomethig();
        dosomethig2();
        dosomething3(); 
    }

    public AlertDialog errormessage()
    {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Fire Missile?")
               .setPositiveButton("Exit!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Fix", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }


    public void guiChanged()
    {
            try{
                DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");

                int CashMoney = sbCash.getProgress();

                tvShwProg.setText("Current Percentage " +CashMoney+ "%");

                double amount = Double.parseDouble(etCash.getText().toString());

                double moneydue = (amount * (CashMoney/100.0));

                double totalamount = (moneydue + amount);

                tvfinal.setText("Tip " + fmt.format(moneydue)+ " Total "+ fmt.format(totalamount));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                errormessage();
                e.printStackTrace();

                etCash.setText("Bro enter a number here");
            }

    }            


    public void dosomethig()
    {

        btnten.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sbCash.setProgress(10);


            }
        });
    }
    public void dosomethig2()
    {

        btntwenty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sbCash.setProgress(15);
            }


        });
    }
    public void dosomething3()
    {
        btnthirty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sbCash.setProgress(20);

            }
        });
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
   05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): ANR in com.Shashank.nchs.Final_exam.hayes (com.Shashank.nchs.Final_exam.hayes/.MainActivity)
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): Load: 0.57 / 0.57 / 0.27
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): CPU usage from 21865ms to -1ms ago:
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   12% 431/com.Shashank.nchs.Final_exam.hayes: 10% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 1929 minor 1 major
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0.4% 176/logcat: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   1.3% 41/adbd: 0.1% user + 1.1% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   1.3% 71/system_server: 1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 102 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0% 124/jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0.4% 141/com.android.launcher: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 50 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0.3% 199/android.process.acore: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 39 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0.2% 255/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 315 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0.2% 267/com.android.defcontainer: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 37 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0% 31/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0% 115/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   0% 136/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): 34% TOTAL: 24% user + 9.1% kernel + 0.5% softirq
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): CPU usage from 1008ms to 1562ms later:
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   53% 431/com.Shashank.nchs.Final_exam.hayes: 48% user + 5% kernel / faults: 265 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     32% 431/inal_exam.hayes: 30% user + 2.5% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     8.7% 434/GC: 8.7% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     2.5% 437/Compiler: 2.5% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     1.2% 433/HeapWorker: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   5.4% 71/system_server: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     5.4% 95/InputDispatcher: 1.8% user + 3.6% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     1.8% 76/Compiler: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   5.4% 176/logcat: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   3.7% 371/com.svox.pico: 3.7% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     2.4% 371/com.svox.pico: 2.4% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   3.6% 41/adbd: 1.8% user + 1.8% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     7.2% 41/adbd: 3.6% user + 3.6% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     3.6% 161/adbd: 1.8% user + 1.8% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):     1.8% 162/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71):   1.1% 267/com.android.defcontainer: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
    05-12 19:44:27.144: E/ActivityManager(71): 100% TOTAL: 85% user + 14% kernel
```

Comment: please post your logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when no input given and alert dialog not fixing the error

because currently you are returning `AlertDialog.Builder` instance from `errormessage()` method and not calling `AlertDialog.show()` for showing Dialog. so you will need to `alert.show()` to show `AlertDialog`. do it as:

```
      try{
          guiChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialog alert =errormessage();
             alert.show(); //<<< show AlertDialog here
        }
```

Comment: Dude thanks this works, actually this try catch is extra if you add the .Show() at the errormessega() that will work, but this works.

Comment: One last Question, For every time i pull it the error dialog come up many times and not just once, how do i fix it so it only shows up when there is no input

Comment: @user2375589 : this happens because u are showing Alert in `onTextChanged` method which called every time when user type and char in Edittext so to avoid this bug you will need to first check `if(alert.isShowing())` before showing Alert if it's already showing then first call cancel before showing alert

Comment: ok i tried it and it worked very well thanks for your help and stack overflow i don't know if i could have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to get sure that there is an input at Your editText etCash. I don´t know exactly what You are trying to do, but if the user should give some input into the etCash, You can get sure, that there is only a number input by setting this attributes to Your etCash inside xml layout. For example:

```
        android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

or

```
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

this depends on what You want. I think in Your case, "numberDecimal" is the best way.

Also, You can check before parsing:

```
     if(etCash.getText().toString().length()<1){
              //show warning
     }
```

If you want to check if input is a number:

```
    private boolean isNumeric(String str){

for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
     }
   return true;
  }
```

Comment: Ok i am going to try this but can you just put the dialog on the  
///
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {} 
////
instead of this piece of code because it should just show one once as its a start!